# Using a recipe within CaretList

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, training-data, recipe

I've been trying to use a recipe within CaretList to train a list of models.

```
library(data.table)
library(caretEnsemble)
library(recipe)
library(doParallel)


data(iris)
dat <- setDT(iris)[Species %in% c("setosa","versicolor"),]
#my real dataset has a combination of factor and numeric columns
dat[,`:=`(
factor_test = factor(ifelse(Sepal.Length>4.8,1,0),
Species = factor(Species, levels = c("setosa","versicolor"))] # adjust factor levels for species

blueprint <- recipe(Species ~., data=dat) %>% step_nzv(all_predictors()) %>%  step_pca(matches("Sepal.Width|Petal.Length"), prefix = "WidthLength_",  threshold = .95)

# set seeds for tuning caret models
set.seed(42)
seed.list <- list()
for (i in 1:100) {
  seed.list[[i]] <- sample.int(n = 100000000, size = 50000)
}
seed.list[[101]] <- sample.int(n = 100000000, size = 1)

# LGOCV in lieu of repeated cross-validation on separate train and test sets
myControl <- trainControl(method = "LGOCV", 
                              number = 3,
                              p = 0.7,
                              summaryFunction = multiClassSummary, 
                              classProbs = TRUE, 
                              verboseIter = TRUE,
                              seeds = seed.list,  
                              savePredictions = "all",
                              returnResamp = "all",
                              allowParallel = TRUE)

cl <- makePSOCKcluster(detectCores()-1)
registerDoParallel(cl)

test_list <- caretList(blueprint,
                       data = dat,
                       methodList = list("glm","gbm"),
                       metric = "AUC")
stopCluster(cl)
```

CaretList documentation says to provide the same inputs as in "train" to "modelList" but I keep getting the error "Error in extractCaretTarget.default(...) : argument "y" is missing, with no default" even though the recipe is correct. What am I doing wrong here?
P.S. Please comment if the set-up of LGOCV is incorrect, this is my first time using...

Answer (score 0):

just ran into this same issue. an extractCaretTarget is an S3 method and one doesn't exist for the recipe class yet, it's using this method to create the resamples. If the resamples are passed in upfront, it tries to generated them and needs the outcome y to make stratified folds

```
if (is.null(trControl$index)) {
   target <- extractCaretTarget(...)
        trControl <- trControlCheck(x = trControl, y = target)
    }
```

might be able to get around this by explicitly setting the index argument when declaring the trainControl

```
if(x$method=="boot" | x$method=="adaptive_boot"){
      x$index <- createResample(y, times = x$number, list = TRUE)
    } else if(x$method=="cv" | x$method=="adaptive_cv"){
      x$index  <- createFolds(y, k = x$number, list = TRUE, returnTrain = TRUE)
    } else if(x$method=="repeatedcv"){
      x$index <- createMultiFolds(y, k = x$number, times = x$repeats)
    } else if(x$method=="LGOCV" | x$method=="adaptive_LGOCV"){
      x$index <- createDataPartition(
        y,
        times = x$number,
        p = 0.5,
        list = TRUE,
        groups = min(5, length(y)))
    }
```